# How to use select() in chat client program in C socket programming?

Tags: c, sockets, select, nonblocking

I'm newbie.

I want to make the client program to receive input from keyboard and data from server. I don't want if while user type something (scanf) and its block to receive data from server.

How to write the code in C ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome :)

I suggest grabbing a copy of [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd Edition](http://www.apuebook.com/) as soon as you can. It has excellent examples on using `select()` (and everything else, too).

The source code package on the page above includes an excellent example, `calld/loop.c` that shows more or less exactly what you want -- a server loop that accepts connections, adds the connections to the select mask of file descriptors, and handles file descriptors in turn.

If you'd like a friendlier interface, investigate [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/). Libevent can give you higher performance on a wide range of platforms *and* a nice interface. Great for production code, maybe less great for learning how the kernel works.

Comment: Maybe add Beej's guide ( http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/ ) as a quickly accessible, free resource?